# MYSQL Match Records between 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

```
tb1
OLD_id | East | North
1      | 1000 | 2000

tb2
NEW_id | East | North
4000   | 1009 | 1995
```

For all records in "tb1" I need to find all records from "tb2" that match the following conditions

```
tb2.East between (tb1.East - 10) and (tb1.East + 10)
tb2.North between (tb1.North - 10) and (tb1.North + 10)
```

Output

```
OLD_id | Matching NEW_ID's | East Difference | North Difference
1      | 4000              | 9               | -5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT t1.OLD_id, t2.new_id `Matching NEW_ID''s`, t2.East - t1.East `East Difference`, t2.North - t1.North `North Difference` FROM tb1 t1
  JOIN tb2 t2
  ON 
    t2.East BETWEEN t1.East - 10 AND t1.East + 10 AND
    t2.North BETWEEN t1.North - 10 AND t1.North + 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query

```
select * 
from 
tb1 
  join tb2 on (tb2.East between tb1.East - 10 and tb1.East + 10) 
  and (tb2.North between   tb1.North - 10 and tb1.North + 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT tb1.OLD_id,tb2.NEW_id AS Matching_NEW_ID's,(tb1.East-tb2.East) AS East_Difference, (tb2.North-tb1.North) AS North_Difference FROM tb1,tb2 WHERE "CONDITIONS"
```